# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary<Swift.String, Swift.Double>' (0x11b1b84f8) to 'NSMutableDictionary'

Tags: objective-c, swift, crash, type-conversion

I'm calling a method which is written in Objective C,

```
-(void)fetchWithDetails:(NSMutableDictionary*)details
                  success:(void (^)(id response))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error,NSString *userMessage))failure;
```

In Swift I'm calling the objective C method as :

```
ULWebServiceStoreUtility.fetch(withDetails: parameters as! NSMutableDictionary , success: { (response) in ....}, failure: { error, userMessage in ...})
```

But I'm getting crash error : Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary' (0x11b1b84f8) to 'NSMutableDictionary'

So could somebody guide me how to pass NSMutableDictionary in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is not directly castable to `NSMutableDictionary`. The types are different.

You probably need something like this:

```
fetch(withDetails: NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: parameters), ...)
```